# 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java

getting an unusual error:- 'void' type not allowed here

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

 public class MiniMusicPlayer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
                    Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
                    Track track = seq.createTrack();
                    for (int i = 5; i < 61; i += 4) {
                            track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, i, 100, i));
                            track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, i, 100, i));
                    }

                            player.setSequence(seq);
                            player.setTempoInBPM(220);
                            player.start();



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace());
            }
    }

    public static MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int ch, int note, int vel,
                    int tick) {
            MidiEvent event = null;
            try
            {
                    ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
                    a.setMessage(comd, ch, note, vel);
                    event = new MidiEvent(a,tick);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return event;
    }
```

ankit@battlestar:/home/mount_150/Java$ javac MiniMusicPlayer1.java 
MiniMusicPlayer1.java:21: error: 'void' type not allowed here
            System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace());
                                                 ^

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling `printStackTrace` and "passing" its void result to `println`.

`println` requires something to print: all you need is `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: its a bit meh that println can't just handle this.. :/

Comment: @Arnab: what in Hades are you talking about? How can println possibly handle something if no viable information is passed to it? 1+ to Dave.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I am saying that it sucks that println can't handle void values being passed to it. Not that it would do anything useful though, except for maybe avoid the awkward compiler error message. Alternatively of course, the compiler error message could be improved by stating what kinds of input println can handle, and what it actually got

Comment: @Arnab: the compiler error is just fine and tells exactly what the problem is: that a method is being called with the wrong arguments. I think your point is a non-issue. The API also has all the information needed as to what the method is expecting.

Comment: @ArnabDatta - I think you are expecting too much of the Java compiler.  It is simply not practical for a compiler to attempt to try and figure out what newbie users *mean* when they write something that is invalid.  (Frankly, a lot of the time it is not even possible for a human to figure that out ... without relying on various high level hints in the newbie's questions / comments.)

Comment: I am not saying that the compiler error isn't fine. I'm saying it isn't good enough. What is it referring to when it says "void type not allowed here" ? Is it the println that's the void in question? (It is a void, but it is not *the* void)

Comment: In addition to what Dave says, by default ex.printStackTrace(); prints to STD_ERR. You can specify where to print the stack-trace to by using printStackTrace(PrintStream). For example, in your code it appears that you're trying to print the exception to STD_OUT instead of STD_ERR, and this can be accomplished as follows: ex.printStackTrace(System.out);.

Comment: @StephenC : Well, atm it points out that there's a void type that's the problem. It isn't exactly a stretch to imagine that the compiler *could* point out what the input type should be. 

Of course, this is entirely up to the programmers of the compilers to figure out how much they want to babysit their users, but my 2c on this is: if an error message isn't explicit enough for a 5yr old, it isn't explicit enough. 

But I feel I've digressed too far away from the thread, so let's just agree to disagree :)

Comment: *"maybe avoid the awkward compiler error message"*  Having seen many code snippets that compiled fine but failed (silently) at run-time, I disagree.  Whether the compiler message could be better is another matter.  *"What is it referring to when it says "void type not allowed here" ?"*  The compiler messages generally include a little `^` on the previous line, to show exactly where in the code line, nonsense was detected.  My advice is to stop complaining about what the compiler reports, and learn to understand it.

Comment: @ArnabDatta It's referring to the only thing that can't be void there, the parameter to `println`. What `println` accepts is documented, and what it "should" be is one of nine possibilities. It's not clear to me that it's better to pollute the compilation output with a paragraph of text already available in the Javadocs. Some languages *do* attempt to guess what was intended, but I'm at least as meh about that. You could always file an enhancement request to spew the Javadocs of the method being called if it doesn't get a valid argument, but I'd vote against it in terms of ROI.

Comment: @Dave, is the error due to the void return type of the printStackTrace Method under java.lang.Exception class.?

Comment: @ankit ... You can't pass "void" as an argument, void is the *absense* of any value. So yes, as I said, the error is because you're using the result of printStackTrace as a parameter to something that requires a parameter. All you need to do is printstacktrace.